# adb shell operation not permitted

Tags: android, adb

I try to run

```
adb shell kill 5539
```

where `5539` is a process id found when running `adb shell ps`, but I get

```
/system/bin/sh: kill: 5539: Operation not permitted
```

How can I rectify my permissions?

This is the only adb documentation on kill:

> kill [options]
>
> Kill all processes associated with  (the app's package name).
>   This command kills only processes that are safe to kill and that will
>   not impact the user experience. Options are:
>
> --user  | all | current: Specify user whose processes to kill; all users if not specified.

Comment: did you try `kill -9`?  BTW, do you have root privileges? http://mail.kde.org/pipermail/necessitas-devel/2011-June/000139.html

Answer (score 23):

My methods:

**Without root**

```
adb shell am force-stop <package name>
```

I don't know how to do it with PID, `kill <PID>` and `kill -9 <PID>` don't work in my case

**With root**

I have also installed [BusyBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=pl) to get more UNIX tools on my device

```
adb shell "su -c 'kill $(pidof <package name>)'"
```

or

```
adb shell "su -c 'kill <PID>'"
```

Comment: +1 nice answer, but `adb shell "su -c kill 101"` works for me (without `'`). Thanks :)

Comment: Although `force-stop` is useful, it is different to using `kill`. `force-stop` will change how Android OS treats that app. For example, push notifications are no longer delivered to the app.

Answer (score 12):

You need to restart adb as root

This will give you permissions to kill the process.

> $ adb root
>
> $ adb shell kill 5539

Comment: adb root doesn't help.

Comment: `adb root` doesn't work on a real device, but emulator API 30 works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with real device and I couldn't get root access.

When I run the command: `adb root`

I got the following error: `adbd cannot run as root in production builds`

I solved it by using the emulator. The emulator allows you to get root access.

**Run your app on the emulator and then run these commands:**

```bash
adb root

adb shell ps | grep com.your.app_package | awk '{print $2}' | xargs adb shell kill
```

The second command finds the `PID` of the app and kills it, if you don't know the `PID`.
or you can use your command:

```bash
adb shell kill <PID>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only access the database of my emulator, not my device. Start the emulator using `emulator -avd <device name>` where you can find the device name by running `android avd`.